# Default argument v templates priority in overload resolution

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have a function overload set similar to

```
template<typename T> void f(T&& t, int x = 1);
void f(int x = 0);
```

Which of these will be called in preference if I call `f` with an integer argument? e.g.

```
f(5);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void f(int x = 0);` will be called. During overload resolution, a non-template is always preferred over a template when the argument type is an exact match (i.e., needs no conversions) – see §13.3.3/1.

(Note that if the non-template overload were instead `void f(long x = 0);` and the callsite remained the same, or if the overload remained the same but the callsite were instead `f(5L);`, the template overload would be invoked instead.)